# Where is This Mystery Print Job Hiding?

Tags: mac-osx, printing, print-server

We have a OS X server running a print share.  Papercut is used to charge people for printing. Someone sent a problem document to a printer, which caused the printer to give a RIP error and completely freeze.  The document tries to print each time we reboot the printer.

What I'm wondering is where exactly this document is hiding.

It's not on the machine that sent the print job, that machine is turned off.

It doesn't appear to be in the print queue on the server.  Actually the print queue has been paused and empty, yet the document is sent to the printer repeatedly.

It doesn't appear in the cups queue in var, we cleared all the binary files manually.  Even shutting off the CUPS system completely doesn't help, the job keeps on trying to print over and over.

The print job is not being stored in the printer memory.  Doing a factory reset, leaving it unplugged overnight, and doing several manual 'reset print service' on the printers managment page has no effect.  Also, to confirm this the print job does not print while the ethernet is unplugged.  Once you plug it in the printer says 'network busy', starts printing, then freezes and shows the RIP error.

Answer (score 1):

To verify its really really not the RIP device, power up the printer without a network cable, then change the IP in the printer. Reconnect the network cable-see if it starts spooling up. RIP printers do a lot of weird things with spooling. 
On the OS X server if you do lpstat -t at the command line, the troublesome job doesn't appear at all? If it doesn't, its certainly not in CUPS.